# Dateserial() strange behavior

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please explain to me why this code:

```
MsgBox DateSerial(Int(Val(Left("20180618", 4))), Int(Val(Mid("20180618", 3, 2))), Int(Val(Right("20180618", 2))))
```

returns **6/18/2019**???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Mid("20180618", 3, 2)` is `18`, which overflows the 12 months in a year and bumps up the year number by one.

Apparently you meant `Mid("20180618", 5, 2)`.

Coincidentally, the difference between `Mid("20180618", 5, 2)` and `Mid("20180618", 3, 2)` is exactly 12 (months), so you are only seeing the year changing and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Your middle value is returning the wrong desired number, use this for your mid value instead

```
Int(Val(Mid("20180618", 5, 2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are having lots of arguments, which are evaluated to something different in the code, try to see what is the evaluation of every argument for itself. `Debug.Print` is a good way to see it:

```
Sub Main()

    Debug.Print (Left("20180618", 4))
    Debug.Print (Mid("20180618", 3, 2))
    Debug.Print (Right("20180618", 2))

End Sub
```

Thus, you would get:

```
2018
18
18
```

And from there it is possible to see the "error". As [mentioned by @GSerg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50640149/5448626), when more than 12 months are given as a parameter, the year is increased:

`Debug.Print DateSerial(2015,13,1)` returns `01.01.2016`

The same works for days:

`Debug.Print DateSerial(2015,1,363)` returns `29.12.2015`